# Count unique values of a series based on condition - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this.

| booking_id | booking_category | vehicle_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | abc |
| 2 | x | def |
| 3 | y | abc |
| 4 | y | ghi |
| 5 | z | ghi |
| 6 | z | ghi |
| 7 | z | abc |
| 8 | z | abc |
| 9 | x | def |
| 10 | x | ghi |

I need to get the unique count of vehicle_number who have done booking in only 'x' category. For example in this dataframe "def" is the only vehicle_number who have done bookings in "x" category. So the count will be 1.
I dont want to run a loop as it will take lots of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a frequency table with `crosstab`, then check for the counts to make sure only `x` category has count greater than `0`

```
s = pd.crosstab(df['vehicle_number'], df['booking_category'])
m = s.pop('x').ge(1) & s.eq(0).all(1)
```

Details

```
>>> s
booking_category  x  y  z
vehicle_number           
abc               1  1  2
def               2  0  0
ghi               1  1  2

>>> m
vehicle_number
abc    False
def     True
ghi    False
dtype: bool
```

Result

```
>>> m.sum()
1

>>> list(m[m].index)
['def']
```